# Preview image before saving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using Drag and Drop to upload images, but how can I preview my image before saving?

```
var obj = $('.drop');
obj.on('drop', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('border',"2px dotted #bdc3c7");
    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    var file = files[0];
});
```

I've been looking around and found about `FileReader` but I have no idea how to implement

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hardiksondagar/t6UP5/

Comment: @Vineet this must be an answer section

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preview an image before it is uploaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Comment: @user2181397 Please check now. :)\

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <br>
    <img id="blah" src="http://i.imgur.com/zAyt4lX.jpg" alt="your image" height="100" />
</form>
```

And your JS part :

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
```

I hope it helps. Please take a look on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hardiksondagar/t6UP5/)